# Writing a trigger for AFER Update on DB2

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

I want to set the column `EDI_INVOICE` to False whenever the `DOCUMENT_TYPE` is a REBILL for only specific `BILL_TO_CODES`

This is how I wrote my trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER BT_CU_CASS_REBILLS
AFTER UPDATE OF DOCUMENT_TYPE ON TLORDER 
REFERENCING OLD AS O NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL 
BEGIN ATOMIC 
     IF N.DOCUMENT_TYPE <> O.DOCUMENT_TYPE AND N.DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'REBILL' 
     AND N.BILL_TO_CODE IN (SELECT TRADING_PARTNER FROM EDI_PROFILES WHERE EDI_TYPE = '210' AND EDI_ACTIVE = 'True' AND UPPER(FTP_ADDRESS) LIKE '%CASS%')
     THEN SET N.EDI_INVOICE = 'True';
     END IF; 
     END
```

But when trying to execute the Query to create the trigger I get this Error

```
SQL0797N The Trigger Lynx.BT_CU_CASS_REBILLS is defined with an unsporrted triggered SQL statement. Line Number = 11. SQLSTATE = 42987
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the trigger to change the data in the row for which the trigger is firing, ie.

```
THEN SET N.EDI_INVOICE = 'True';
```

you need to use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.

Comment: Thank you so much you were right and it worked like a charm!